# How State is specific to the specific environment, when its actually pushed to all environments with DB sync?

Tags: 8

I am working with a Drupal 8 setup when production, test and development environments which periodically sync database. In Drupal 7 it was easy to override the $conf variables in `settings.php` to force a site in maintenance mode. However, in Drupal 8, the maintenance_mode is not a configuration anymore, but a state that is not possible to override from settings.php, so we have to use additional `drush` command after each sync to put one of the environments to maintenance mode.

And I am confused how come State API documentation asserts it's environment-specific, when in fact, it gets synced together with database and it is not easy to keep environment-specific settings using State API.

On the contrary, $config is easy to override in `settings.php` (which is excluded during sync), so it does provide easy way of setting environment-specific configurations.

Comment: Code and configuration always goes upstream (local > dev > stage > prod) while a database only goes downstream (prod > stage > dev > local).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you copy your development/testing database to your production
database, you're effectively replacing your production site's state
with your development site's state. Therefore if you put your
production site in maintenance mode, then import a database that says
the site is not in maintenance mode, then your site will stop being in
maintenance mode.

Conceptually, state is specific to an environment, so long as you
aren't copying your database when you push changes from development to
production.

Your solution may be to avoid doing these database imports altogether.
If you are just making configuration changes on your local development
site and just need to push those, you can export the site's
configuration to code, commit it to version control, push that config
to production and then import it. (See
https://www.drupal.org/docs/configuration-management for info.)

If you are creating content in the local development environment that
you need to push to production, then you may want to look at using the
[Migrate API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/migrate-api).

If you absolutely must push these database updates but want the
production site to remain in maintenance mode when you do it, then
you'll need to put your development site into maintenance mode before
copying its database to production.

Comment: Fair enough, though I am still confused how they divided the variables to $config and $state. At least some of them, like for example `maintenance_mode` could be considered as misplaced, because by definition States are variables not accessible by and not changed by users regularly. And the `maintenance_mode` can be in fact changed by users and quite frequently.

Comment: Maintenance mode can be changed by site administrators, but it's the status of a specific site, which should not be imported into another site, contrary to (for example) the setting that enables users to create new accounts without administrators authorization.